# It's efficient to use the type of thread StrictMode for a ListView?

Tags: android, strict

It's that efficient? Is there another way to do that? Is it better? Thank you!

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to bypass the `StrictMode` settings. There is nothing efficient about potentially causing your app's UI to freeze.

Answer (score 2):

Nope you should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
 Google introduced AsynchTask to clear the ANR problem.
 Though your method works, but your application will lag if your network request take some time.
 This kind of implementation is not acceptable anymore.
And example [here](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.U0c9P_k72So).